# What does flight ID mean here in the picture? It stated in brackets for Performance

Tags: aircraft-performance, fms, checklist, diamond-da40

What does flight ID mean here in the picture? It is stated in brackets for Performance. I searched but couldn't find an answer. I would be glad if you help.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since you tagged [diamond-da40](/questions/tagged/diamond-da40), I assume this is about the G1000 avionics as installed in the DA40. The manual for that G1000 unit is available on the [Garmin website](http://static.garmin.com/pumac/G1000:DiamondPhase6_PilotsGuide.pdf). According to the manual, the **Flight ID** is the aircraft identification transmitted by the Mode S transponder:

> **4.4 GTX 33 MODE S TRANSPONDER**
>
> The GTX 33 Mode S Transponder provides Mode A, Mode C, and Mode S interrogation and reply capabilities.
> Selective addressing or Mode Select (Mode S) capability includes the following features: [...]
>
> - Flight ID (Flight Identification) reporting – The Mode S Transponder reports aircraft identification as either the
>   aircraft registration or a unique Flight ID.

As to why it is under the Performance step: the flight ID is entered on the Timer/References Window, which is the same window where the speed bugs are entered. So it makes sense to have it on this step:

> [image: Timer/References Window]

Comment: That was a very comprehensive and descriptive answer, thank you very much.

Answer (score 3):

The callsign being used for this flight, which will then feed from the FMS into the Mode-S transponder. This is how FlightRadar24 tags your flight.

Comment: I suspect this is indeed the correct answer. Question remains: why is it listed under performance? It could fit under *flight plan* (where the Flight ID is defined) or *Radios* (because the Flight ID is going the transponder, which is a fancy radio transceiver). With performance, the Flight ID has no relation.